# make floated divs stick together even if there 'regular' div between them

Tags: html, css

I have the following code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item can_disappear">2</div>
    <div class="wide"></div>
    <div class="item need_to_be_up">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

the css :

```
.item { 
    width :49%;
    height : 100px;
    float : left;
    background-color:yellow;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.container {
    width :200px;
    position : relative
}

.wide {
    width :100%;
    height : 100px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}
```

[image]

Item #2 can get "display:none".
is there any way that item #3 will go up (will be before the wide div, side to side with the first item) ?

It is not a must that the "wide" div be floated...

here is the jsfiddel : https://jsfiddle.net/edanuf7t/4/
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this cant be best solution but you can solve it thanks of `:after` and `:nth-child(even)` selectors.

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.item { 
 width :49%;
    height : 100px;
    float : left;
    background-color:yellow;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.item:nth-child(even){margin-bottom:100px;position:relative}
.item:nth-child(even):after {display:block;content:" ";height:100%;background:red;width:201px;position:absolute;right:-1px;bottom:-100px}
.item:last-of-type:after {display:none}

.container {
     width :200px;
    position : relative
}
```

and [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/edanuf7t/6/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3-step solution:

1. Re-order the elements, so that `.wide` comes after the `.item`s.
2. Add `margin-bottom: 100px;` to the `.item`s.
3. Give `.wide` a `margin-top: -302px;`

*`302px` rather than `300px`, to account for the top and bottom `1px` border of the second-row items.*

Now, when you apply `display: none;` to any of the floated `.item`s, the following `.item`s will simply float leftward into the newly created space.

```css
.item { 
    width :49%;
    height : 100px;
    float : left;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.container {
    width :200px;
    position : relative
}

.wide {
    float:left;
 margin-top: -302px;
    width :100%;
    height : 100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item can_disappear">2</div>
    <div class="item need_to_be_up">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="wide"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item can_disappear" style="display: none;">2</div>
    <div class="item need_to_be_up">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="wide"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.item:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -202px;
}


-------- (or) -------------


.item:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}


.item:nth-child(4) {
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```